# hibernate connection tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I was working in a web site (production) in Tomcat 7, so now I created a copy of this website and change the hibernate.cfg.xml to work with another database ( testing ).

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">fake</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">fake</property>
```

However, when I open the new new site, everything is ok, but, is still working with the production database even when I changed the connection string.

Anybody knows if I need to change another thing?. I missing something?. I am quite new in tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the database connection is configured elsewhere, and this is a redundant configuration. Usually it is configured in a data source - check your tomcat xml config files, or any xml config files of your application (if using spring, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Datasources in Tomcat can be configured in context.xml file. Most probably that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

might be production database running on different port instead of 3306.